# How to perform action on "Touch inside" on button in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to perform action like changing color of label, when user touches the button but I am unable to find the correct solution in Cocos2d.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited answer after clarifying comment*: if you want to change the color of the button/label or the background sprite frame based on which state the button is in (i.e. normal, highlighted, disabled, selected) you can set the different background/label [properties](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCButton.html#//api/name/setBackgroundColor:forState:), example:

`[button setLabelColor:[CCColor redColor] forState: CCControlStateHighlighted];`

The above example will make the button label flash in red when the button is pressed. If you need more detailed control of what should happen (animations or other) you will need to create a custom subclass of either CCButton or CCControl (which is the base class CCButton inherits from), depending on how complex your needs are, and implement the different [touch event methods.](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCControl.html#//api/name/touchEntered:withEvent:)

Comment: no i know this i wanted to know about touch inside event for CCButton, so when i touch button i can perform action on it.

Comment: what i need is to call method on CCControlStateHighlighted state for now i can only change opacity or color of button, in my case i have cclabel on ccbutton and ccbutton has sprite, so when user touch the button i want to change sprite along with that custom cclabel

Comment: If you look in the documentation link I posted, you'll see that you can change the background sprite frame with the `setBackgroundSpriteFrame:forState:` setter. It allows you to change the sprite to look like it is being pressed down for example. If you need more than that, you'll have to subclass I'm afraid.

Comment: yes i saw that properties but my requirement was to change multiple things on highlighted state like calling a method.

Comment: Ok, then subclassing is the way to go. Please accept my answer, as it answers your original question :)